# how to solve recoverable protocoldecoder exception:the line is too long in android

Tags: android, mina

hi i am new to android i got the response from server using json.when i recieved the response it shows the error here

> 03-22 15:43:46.312: WARN/System.err(541): org.apache.mina.filter.codec.RecoverableProtocolDecoderException: Line is too long:
>
> 03-22 15:43:46.321: WARN/System.err(541):     at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.textline.TextLineDecoder.decodeAuto(TextLineDecoder.java:214)
>
> 03-22 15:43:46.321: WARN/System.err(541):     at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.textline.TextLineDecoder.decode(TextLineDecoder.java:138)
>
> 03-22 15:43:46.321: WARN/System.err(541):     at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter.messageReceived(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:224)
>
> 03-22 15:43:46.321: WARN/System.err(541):     at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:431)

Answer (score 5):

The line you are trying to decode is too long.

TextLineDecoder has a public method called setMaxLineLength which can be used to increase the allowable line length. The default is 1024.

[http://mina.apache.org/report/trunk/apidocs/org/apache/mina/filter/codec/textline/TextLineDecoder.html#setMaxLineLength(int)](http://mina.apache.org/report/trunk/apidocs/org/apache/mina/filter/codec/textline/TextLineDecoder.html#setMaxLineLength%28int%29)

I'm not sure if you are calling TextLineDecoder explicitly in your code. Could you post your code or at least the full stack trace?